# Transpose VBA Excel Macro based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy & transpose values from one Sheet to another Sheet based on a condition, only transpose the first 4 lines looping in large range.

From this:

[image]

To this :

[image]

I've found a transpose macro and adapt it but I couldn't apply the condition.

```
Sub Test()
Set rng = Range("B5", Range("B5").End(xlDown))
Sheets("Example #2").Range(rng).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose()
EndSub
```

Anyone can guide me? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We tried guiding you, posting more answers. What are you doing in terms of feedback sending? It is, at least, polite to follow your question, answer the clarification comments, if any and sending feedback after testing the received solutions...

Comment: I understand and you are right, I think that most of the times I try to leave a comment as feedback but sometimes I forgot to leave one.... I will try to leave a feedback every time since I am not helping this community in the same manner as it has helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It uses arrays, works in memory and will be much faster than copying. This can be easier observed on a large range:

```
Sub CopyTranspose4rows()
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrSl, i As Long
   
   Set sh1 = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need to copy from
   Set sh2 = sh1.Next    'use here what sheet you need to paste
   lastR = sh1.Range("B" & sh1.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row sh1
   
   arr = sh1.Range("B5:B" & lastR).Value 'put the range in an array for fast iteration
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr) Step 4 'iterate from four to four
        With Application
             'create a slice array
             arrSl = .Transpose(.Index(arr, Evaluate("row(" & i & ":" & i + 4 & ")"), 1))
         End With
         'drop the slice array content in the second sheet
         sh2.Range("A" & sh2.rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, 4).Value = arrSl
    Next i
    sh2.Activate 'activate the sheet where pasted
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, this one was the most useful since you don't need to edit the macro in order to put the name of the sheet. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@FaneDuru's array solution is more elegant, but here's another alternative.  You would need to replace the sheet names and the starting cell numbers.

```
Sub TestTranspose()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim LR1 As Long
    Dim x As Long
    
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    LR1 = sht1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    y = 1
    
    For x = 1 To LR Step 4
        sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(x, 2), sht1.Cells(x + 3, 2)).Copy
        sht2.Cells(y, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
        y = y + 1
    Next x
    
End Sub
```

Comment: As you said, @FaneDuru's answer is most helpful for me since I dont need to change the sheet name, but this macro works great too, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With this code you can have different number of answers per question.

```
Sub Tranpose_Questions()
    Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
    Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range
    Dim transRng As Range                                           ' range to transpose
    Dim dstRng As Range: Set dstRng = ActiveSheet.Range("C1")       ' destination cell
    
    ' Value find
    fnd = "Question"
    
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
    Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)
    
    ' Test to see if anything was found
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
    Else
        GoTo errHandler
    End If
    
    Set rng = FoundCell
    
    ' Loop
    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        ' Find next cell
        Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
        Debug.Print rng.Address, FoundCell.Address
        
        ' Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
        If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then
            Set transRng = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
            If rng.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
                transRng.Select: transRng.Copy
                dstRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
            Exit Do
        End If
        
        ' Transpose
        Set transRng = rng.Resize(FoundCell.Row - rng.Row, 1)
        transRng.Copy
        dstRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        ' update rng position
        Set rng = FoundCell
        
        ' update destination range
        Set dstRng = dstRng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    Exit Sub

' Error Handler
errHandler:
    MsgBox "No 'Question' found!"
End Sub
```